# VBA to add a macro to the right mouse click in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm running Word in Office 365; I have a Macro which I can run from a button added to the ribbon, but that requires access to the machine it's running on (at least, the way I did it) and this file is to go out to a distributed workforce.

I'm trying to write a macro in the document which will add a button to the drop-down menu that comes up when you right click on a text selection, but the code below doesn't add anything to the menu.

```
Sub AddToShortcut()
Dim Bar As CommandBar
Dim NewControl As CommandBarButton
DeleteFromShortcut
Set Bar = Application.CommandBars("Standard")
Set NewControl = Bar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=1, Temporary:=True)
With NewControl
    .Caption = "&New Action"
    .OnAction = "AddAction"
    .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
End With
End Sub

Private Sub document_open()
'adds the right-click shortcut when the document opens
Call AddToShortcut
End Sub
```

I got the core of the code from John Walkenbach's Excel VBA Programming for Dummies, so I'm presuming there's some difference between the way Word and Excel operate that's causing the issue?

Comment: AFAIK "Standard" isn't a valid context menu name in Word. There are two ways of editing the context menu's in O365 and you will find both explained in [this article](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_shortcut_menu.html) on Greg Maxeys site

Comment: Thanks, I'd seen that page in my searches, but I'll be honest most of it was just a bit too much of a stretch for me.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add it to the "Text" contextual menu, not "Standard."

Comment: Thank you, that's sort it - it's always the simplest of things!!!

Answer (score 0):

The following is straight from [Greg Maxey's page](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_shortcut_menu.html) that you said was too much. It is the answer, though. Your code would be around oBtn.

You would put this in a [Global Template](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global) stored in your [Word Startup Folder](http://addbalance.com/word/startup.htm) *(links to my pages)*. It could be renamed AutoExec or called from an AutoExec procedure in that template.

```
Option Explicit
Dim oPopUp As CommandBarPopup
Dim oCtr As CommandBarControl

Sub BuildControls()
Dim oBtn As CommandBarButton
  'Make changes to the Add-In template
  CustomizationContext = ThisDocument.AttachedTemplate
  'Prevent double customization
  Set oPopup = CommandBars.FindControl(Tag:="custPopup")
  If Not oPopup Is Nothing Then GoTo Add_Individual
  'Add PopUp menu control to the top of the "Text" short-cut menu
  Set oPopUp = CommandBars("Text").Controls.Add(msoControlPopup, , , 1)
  With oPopUp
   .Caption = "My Very Own Menu"
   .Tag = "custPopup"
   .BeginGroup = True
  End With
  'Add controls to the PopUp menu
  Set oBtn = oPopUp.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
  With oBtn
    .Caption = "My Number 1 Macro"
    .FaceId = 71
    .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
    'Identify the module and procedure to run
    .OnAction = "MySCMacros.RunMyFavMacro"
  End With
  Set oBtn = Nothing
  'Add a Builtin command using ID 1589 (Co&mments)
  Set oBtn = oPopUp.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 1589)
  Set oBtn = Nothing
  'Add the third button
  Set oBtn = oPopUp.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
  With oBtn
    .Caption = "AutoText Complete"
    .FaceId = 940
    .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
    .OnAction = "MySCMacros.MyInsertAutoText"
  End With
  Set oBtn = Nothing
Add_Individual:
  'Or add individual commands directly to menu
  Set oBtn = CommandBars.FindControl(Tag:="custCmdBtn")
  If Not oBtn Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  'Add control using built-in ID 758 (Boo&kmarks...)
  Set oBtn = Application.CommandBars("Text").Controls.Add(msoControlButton, 758, , 2)
  oBtn.Tag = "custCmdBtn"
  If MsgBox("This action caused a change to your Add-In template." _
     & vbCr + vbCr & "Recommend you save those changes now.", vbInformation + vbOKCancel, _
     "Save Changes") = vbOK Then
    ThisDocument.Save
  End If
  Set oPopUp = Nothing
  Set oBtn = Nothing
lbl_Exit:
  Exit Sub
End Sub
```